# Power BI query issue

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am pretty new to BI and am having an irritating issue with adding a column with specific cell values.
I have a column with text, whole numbers, decimal numbers etc. I am only interested in 5 particular cells for my visual. These locations never change but the values update daily with latest refreshed data.
Can anyone help me with making a new column displaying the values of these 5 specific cells only? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY6Fk.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Franco

Comment: What do you mean "making a new column"? To which table you want this column added? How many rows are there and how you can decide in which rows to add each of the values from this new column?

Comment: Hi Andrey. Thanks for your interest. I would like to extract the values from 5 specific rows and place them in a new column in the same table. These 5 row values are whole numbers and are the only data from the original that I am interested in. The rows that are of interest are 12,24,48,60 & 72. Since theses are taken from the source in order, they should be displayed from 1st to 5th in that order(if that makes sense). If it helps, I am looking for something like =Index in Excel where I can set certain values from an array into another location/column. Best regards, Franco

Answer (score 0):

First, you must clearly understand, that Power BI is not like Excel - it does not work with cells, where you can place random values, but with rows. If you add a column to an existing table, you can't just shift values in that column up or down. So in Power BI terms, you either want to filter out (get rid of) the values in rows other than 12, 24, 48, etc. (why you skipped 36? I will assume you want the value of each 12th row), or to keep the source table and make a new table with only one column and values from the rows of interest.

The format of the data you have is sub-optimal, so it will take few steps to extract the important values. One way you can do it is by adding an index column to define a sort order of the rows and add some form of unique identifier. Open Power Query Editor by clicking `Transform data` button in the ribbon and then `Add Column` -> `Index Column` -> `From 1`:

[image]

Then click the button in the `Index` column title and select only the rows that you want to keep (12, 24, 48, 60 and 72):

[image]

This will give you a table with only the rows of interest:

[image]

If you want to keep the source table with all the rows, before filtering the table, right click it in the `Queries` panel and make a duplicate:

[image]

If there is no a finite (and short) list of rows, but you want to keep every 12th row instead, click `Add Column` -> `Custom Column` and add the following:

```
Row of interest = if Number.Mod([Index], 12) = 0 then 1 else 0
```

[image]

And then filter on this column to keep only the rows where `Row of interest = 1`.

Another, more "Power BI", way to do this is to duplicate the table and add `Index Column From 1` in the first copy and `Index Column From 0` in the second one. Then click the drop down of `Merge Queries` and select `Merge Queries as new`. Select `Index` column in both tables to be the key:

[image]

Click on the button in the new column title to expand the table and keep only the values column:

[image]

This will give you the value, which used to be under the title, on the same row now, so now you can filter by title name:

[image]

And you will get this (rename columns if you want):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Andrey for the explanation. I see my mistake now. I was going insane! You are awesome :). Best regards, Franco.